# How long does it take for the Opioids listed in the Description to induce Analgesia when Administered via IV?

Tags: pharmacology, analgesia

How long does it take for the Opioids listed in the Description to induce **Analgesia** when Administered via IV? Now I don't mean how long it takes for euphoria to come on but *analgesia*.

The opioids I would like to know this information to include:

- Buprenorphine
- Butorphanol
- Fentanyl
- Hydromorphone
- Methadone
- Morphine
- Oxycodone
- Pentazocine
- Pethidine (meperidine)
- Sufentanil
- Tramadol

Answer (score 1):

These are 'peak' values when administered via IV, with the exception of oxycodone. There will be some variation person to person depending on their opioid tolerance and any concomitantly administered medications.

Buprenorphine: 60m

Butorphanol: 5m

Fentanyl: 5m

Hydromorphone: 30-90m

Methadone: 1-2h

Morphine: 20m

Oxycodone: Not administered intravenously

Pentazocine: 15m

Sufentanil: 3m

Tramadol: 2h